# error updating python 2.7.12 on xenial

Tags: 16.04, apt, python-2.7

I did the following but still fail to update the python2 to the latest build

**sudo apt update**

**apt list --upgradable**

```
Listing... Done
libpython2.7/xenial-updates,xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13]
libpython2.7-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13]
libpython2.7-minimal/xenial-updates,xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13]
libpython2.7-stdlib/xenial-updates,xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13]
python2.7/xenial-updates,xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13]
python2.7-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13]
python2.7-minimal/xenial-updates,xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13]
```

**sudo apt upgrade**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal
7 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 32.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 18.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-stdlib amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-stdlib amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-dev_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-dev_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-minimal_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal
7 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 32.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 18.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-stdlib amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-stdlib amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-dev_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-dev_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-minimal_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

Comment: This may help you. https://websiteforstudents.com/installing-the-latest-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/  also note 16.04 is EOL in April of this year no support after that.

Comment: I have been upgrading 16.04 -> 18.04 servers for the last couple of weeks and also encountering this issue. Just now am i encountering this error for the first time.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo apt update` as an edit please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package maintainers may have bumped the Python package versions to address https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4754-1. If you look at http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/, you'll see that it still has the previous version 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.13, whereas apt is looking for 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.14. I'm guessing the upstream Packages.gz (package list) contains the bumped version of the package, but the mirror doesn't actually have the new package version it's referring to.

Edit: looks like the updated packages now exist in the repo. Confirmed with a Docker build of Xenial that installs Python 2.7.

Comment: Correct, this seems an issue with the remote archive. "It's not you." Noticed that the `xenial-security` archive on the `archive.ubuntu.com` does not yet claim to have this .14 version in the Packages file (probably lagging behind on mirroring security). update: confirmed that it's fixed while I was typing this comment.

Comment: confirmed fixed.

Comment: Thanks @rgs! today it worked, as you wrote the files were probably not in sync when I tried. Thanks all for the input